# Finding $\int \frac {e^x \sqrt{e^x - 1}}{e^x+3}\,dx$ by substituting $t^2=e^x-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Let's consider the following integral:

$$\int \frac {e^x \sqrt{e^x - 1}}{e^x+3}\,dx$$

And let's take the substitution $t^2=e^x-1$. Then, we get $2tdt=e^xdx$ and so:

$$\int \frac {e^x \sqrt{e^x - 1}}{e^x+3}\,dx = 2\int \frac {t \sqrt{t^2}}{t^2+4}\,dt$$

So, can we take $\sqrt{t^2}=t$ there? It seems to me that we could do that only if we say at the beginning, when we took the substitution, that $t$ is non-negative. However, I've never seen that anybody has  written anything like that in any solution of antiderivative problems. So, if we want to be formal, should we write that we take non-negative $t$?

Answer (score 8):

It makes a difference on how we define our substituition.By taking $e^x-1=t^2$ we could have $t=\pm\sqrt{e^x-1}$.

To avoid this problem I would take $\sqrt{e^x-1}=t$ which would *automatically* mean $t\ge 0$. Hence we have to evaluate $$2\int \frac{t^2dt}{t^2+4}$$ which is easy to do by hand...

Comment: Yep, that's true for this example, but what if we have some functions $f,g$ and we want to substitute $f(u) = g(x)$, but the following holds: 1) there are multiple $u$ which would satisfy the equation 2) we can't define $u$ as a function of $x$ 3)there is a square root with $u^2$ under it after the substitution?

Comment: @frgt can you give me an example ?

Comment: It is not an example of the situation above, but the following is kinda in the same spirit. How can we take $u=\sqrt{x}$ while solving $\int \frac {1}{\sqrt{2x^2+3x}}\,dx$ when the domain of the function contains negative numbers too? The substitution is used on https://www.integral-calculator.com/ too, so how can we overcome that issue?

Comment: @frgt if $2x^2+3x<0$ then the $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+3x}}$ is not defined so such a question can never be asked

Comment: I didn't mean that. What I said was that the function is well defined for example for $-2$, so how can we take $u=\sqrt{x}$, when $x$ can be negative too?

Comment: In fact, it is easy, one can write $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+3x}}\,dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(x+\frac{3}{4})^2 - 2\frac{3}{4}^2}}\,dx$ and then take $u=x+ \frac{3}{4}$.